# The right way to update a rails association by passing a value other than the primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm a new-ish Rails dev, I'm trying to optimize part of my app, but having a hard time ferreting out the rails convention way to achieve what I want. I have a 'Location' model to which one user can be assigned as the default contact. This is captured by a default_contact_id key in the Location table that references the 'User' model. In the location edit view I would like a user to be able to input the desired default_contact by writing the email address in a text box. However I struggled with how to implement this - I tried messing around with fields_for, but I don't ultimately want to update the associated user object, just the association itself (which is stored in location). I also don't want to use a dropdown even though it would nicely give the user_id, as there are potentially dozens or hundreds of users that could be assigned as the default contact.

I ended up building an attr_accessor in the Location model to temporarily take the desired email address, and then added logic to the controller/helper to update the value based on the input. But this is pretty verbose, gives a double-database hit, and really doesn't seem like 'The Rails Way'. Is there a more slick way to achieve this that I'm totally missing?

This is the current hacked-together solution:

**Location.rb**:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :default_contact, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'default_contact_id', optional: true

  attr_accessor :default_contact_email
end
```

**views\locations\edit.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Update Location</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_with(model: @location) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object  %>

      ... other fields ...
    
      <%= f.label :default_contact_email %>
      <%= f.email_field :default_contact_email, :value => @location.default_contact.email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Update Location", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**locations_controller.rb**:

```
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    
    if @location.update(update_location_params)
      set_default_contact(@location)
      flash[:success] = "Location updated"
      redirect_to @location
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Changes were not saved"
      render 'edit', status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def update_location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:name, :business_unit_id, :default_contact_email)
    end
```

**locations_helper.rb**

```
  def set_default_contact(loc)
        
    if loc.default_contact_id.nil? or (loc.default_contact && ( loc.default_contact.email != loc.default_contact_email ))
      
      if loc.default_contact_email == nil
        loc.default_contact_id = nil
      elsif
        u = User.find_sole_by(email: loc.default_contact_email)
        loc.default_contact_id = u.id
      end
      loc.save
    end
  end
```

PS - yes, there is database constraint that user email's must be unique. In Schema for users table:

```
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the accessor and just apply the login inside the controller with something like this.

```rb
def update
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])

  @location.default_contact = User.find_by(email: params[:location][:default_contact_email])

  # other stuff for updating
end
```

You don't need those extra checks because `.find_by` will return `nil` if it doesn't find a user(even when the email value is nil)

Comment: Derp! Thank you. Face palm on my end when I tried your ultra-simple solution and realized it worked. I was avoiding it because I thought that ```@location.update(update_location_params)``` would only update the literal params and not capture changes made earlier to @location (i.e. assigning a new default_contact). Rails is amazing in that it captures that!

Comment: There were a couple more tricks to doing this, but it set me on the right path. After deleting the accessor I also had to change the form in the view to use an ```<%= email_field_tag :default_contact_email ... ``` and update the strong params as there was obviously no longer an attribute on the model. All working now though and much cleaner!

Comment: @NickGobin Yep on the second comment! Missed it when writing an answer :)